# Creating directories and files within

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, console-application

I've seen a lot of tutorials online about how you can edit files with c, how to write data within a text file and similar things.Like this code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>  /* For exit() function */
  int main()
  {
     char sentence[1000];
     FILE *fptr;

   fptr = fopen("program.txt", "w");
   if(fptr == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error!");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
   gets(sentence);

   fprintf(fptr,"%s", sentence);
   fclose(fptr);

   return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to make a folder, in VS there are four folders for use I.E 
External Dependencies, 
Header files, 
Resource files, 
Source files; 
I'd like to make it possible to create another folder and within it store text files or another directories.
And after then I can delete the file or directory. Like that I can create the file within the code without any need to do that outside the programme.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: POSIX defines `mkdir()` to create a directory.

Comment: the question is about the organization of a 'project' within Visual Studio, not about actual directories on a disk

Comment: Yes it is, I managed to read the data from a txt file within a specific location attached to the project folder, But a problem comes that I can't use the content of the txt file for the locations. Can someone help with that too?